# Compare values in 2 lists and import the bigger value in a 3rd list

Tags: python, list, compare

I have started learning python and programming in general a few days ago just for fun and i've encountered a small roadblock.
I'm trying to compare the values in 2 user generated lists and add the bigger value between each counter increment in a 3rd list such as:
    a = [1 2 3]
    b = [3 4 1]
the result should be 
    c = [3 4 3]

```
sa = input("The first list is: ")
myList = list(map(int, sa.split()))
sb = input("The second list is: ")
myList2 = list(map(int, sb.split()))
myList3 = []
i=0
for i in range(len(myList)):
   if myList[i] > myList2[i]:
          myList3[i] = myList[i]
   else: myList3[i] = myList2[i]
print(myList3)
```

This is my code so far but i am getting an "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Comment: `c = [max(a_item, b_item) for a_item, b_item in zip(a,b)]` or `list(map(max,a,b))`

Comment: You will get the error as long as the length of `myList` is greater than the length of  `myList2`

Comment: OP, note that looping through `list`s is better done like so `for item in myList` or if you really need the indexes, `for i, item in enumerate(myList)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `myList3.append(myList[i])` and `myList3.append(myList2[i])` instead of `myList3[i] = myList[i]` and `myList3[i] = myList2[i]`, since the index doesn't exist yet so you can't assign it directly

Comment: Where exactly in the code do i add those? I've tried before the for loop and i still get the out of range error

Comment: oh sorry, instead of `myList3[i] = myList[i]` and the other call right below it

Answer (score 0):

`zip` your lists

```
In [66]: zip(a, b)
Out[66]: ((1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1))
```

Iterate through the sequence and find out the `max` item of zipped `tuple`.

```
In [64]: [max(i) for i in zip(a, b)]
Out[64]: [3, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that a more Pythonic way to do that would be this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 1]
c = [max(i) for i in zip(a, b)]
print(c)  # [3, 4, 3]
```

If it can be the case that the two `list`s do not have the same number of items you can use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [1, 2, 3, 7]
b = [3, 4, 1]
c = [max(i) for i in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)]
print(c)  # [3, 4, 3, 7]
```